# Timeout expires during database restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using this query to restore a database from a C++ program

```
RAISERROR ('-- Performing full restore...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT 
USE MASTER; 
ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
RESTORE DATABASE [{0}] FROM  DISK = N'{1}'  
WITH  FILE = 1, REPLACE, KEEP_REPLICATION, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5;
ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
RAISERROR ('-- Performing full restore: Done', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

On my computer it works as intended, but when I try to restore the database on our customer's computer an error message pops out saying

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. The backup or restore
>   was aborted.

And this shows right after this info shows up

> Processed 1768 pages for database '[database]', file '[logic_name]'
>   on file 1. Processed 4 pages for database '[database]', file
>   '[logic_name]_log' on file 1.

I checked the **NETWORK SERVICE** user and it has access to the folder of the .bak file. I noticed that under the general Security options (not the ones just for the database I want to restore, the outer ones in the tree of the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) the **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** user was missing, so I created it with the same options as the one I have on my computer right now, but this didn't change anything.

I set the LockTimeOut to 0 (it was -1), but again, nothing changed.

What can cause this timeout expiration? And how can I have different behaviour on different computers? I guess there is some option that I'm missing, but I really don't know what else to do.
Thanks!

P.S.: this is the query I use to back up the database

```
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BACKUP DATABASE [{0}] TO  DISK = N'{1}' 
WITH NAME = N'program-Full Database Backup', STATS = 10;
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no problem with permissions (otherwise you'd got "access denied" or "file not found" errors), nither it's a lock timeout. This timeout is set up in your C++ program, if I'm not mistaken, 30 seconds is the default. SQL Server has no timeouts at all, you should change the property in your application, smth like SqlCommand.CommandTimeout

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much. I thought it was not actually the C++ program, because it should have been slower on my machine since I had the same database, but running through Visual Studio. Anyway, thanks :)